# UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() failed to get the current CGContext

Tags: ios, swift, uigraphicscontext

I came across an example in a book for learning iOS 13 programming.The example intends to draw an arrow like the one in the following picture:

[image]

The code for the example is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        drawArrow()
    }

    func drawArrow () {
        // obtain the current graphics context
        guard let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        // draw a black (by default) vertical line, the shaft of the arrow
        con.move(to: CGPoint(100, 100))
        con.addLine(to: CGPoint(100, 19))
        con.setLineWidth(20)
        con.strokePath()
        // draw a red triangle, the point of the arrow
        con.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        con.move(to: CGPoint(80, 25))
        con.addLine(to: CGPoint(120, 25))
        con.fillPath()
        // snap a triangle out of the shaft by drawing in Clear blend mode
        con.move(to: CGPoint(90, 101))
        con.addLine(to: CGPoint(100, 90))
        con.addLine(to: CGPoint(110, 101))
        con.setBlendMode(.clear)
        con.fillPath()
    }
}
```

However, when run, the line of code `guard let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }` failed to produce the CGContext instance as expected. I'm not sure why it is like that. Would you please help explain why and suggest a solution to the issue? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's my book and my arrow and you didn't follow the directions in the book. The example tells you to be in a UIView subclass and that this code should be called from your `draw(_:)` override.

Comment: See https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/604368f458076dd40a8f4d0676a2aa79adb8e390/bk2ch02p077drawingInUIView/ch15p427drawingInUIView/MyView.swift for working examples of this and _all_ the code in the book

Comment: Thank you very much, @matt, for your immediate help! I'm surprised and happy to get the answer from the author of the book himself! I'm sorry that I only focused on the code snippet in the book and forgot to consult the full-code examples provided by you. Turned pages too fast when reading the Preface :). Thanks again for your help!